# Lists accept iterable objects as inputs. However, when the input is an int or float, e.g. list(1), this is not accepted. Why?

Tags: python, list, iterable

I was experimenting with list properties while doing Python exercises on inheritance and class objects. I realised that `list([1,2,3])` is valid as a list itself is an iterable but something like `list(1)` will return an error. Isn't a single object in itself an iterable? However, a string with multiple characters like list("this is a list") does not return an error, further adding to my confusion (Granted, a string is a single object). Why is that the case?

```
from  cpython/listobject.c (starting line 2675)
/*[clinic input]
list.__init__
    iterable: object(c_default="NULL") = ()
    /
Built-in mutable sequence.
If no argument is given, the constructor creates a new empty list.
The argument must be an iterable if specified.
[clinic start generated code]*/
```

I've looked at the source code for the list class at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c and it seems line 2675-2721 might have the answer I'm looking for but as a novice, I need someone to explain the process of creating a list to me.

Comment: A string is interable (it iterates over the characters of the string). An int isn't interable though.

Comment: A `list` is a single object, just as an `int` is. Some objects (like `list`s) are iterable, others (like `int`s) are not.

Comment: You have answered your own question in the title, really…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list()` function only accepts iterables. Iterables are objects that can be iterated over. There is no way a program can iterate over an integer, but it *can* iterate over a single-character string.